# Arrays juggling - data preparation

Tags: c#, arrays

I could use some advice or help regarding a problem i'm facing and can't figure out a decent algorithm or solution.

Here's the status:
I have a 2D array of shorts: `short[][] signal` one dimension is the so-called channels. So depending on the problem i may have from 1 to 128. My test cases have 60 channels. And the other dimension represents "time" - 2048 samples per second and the samples are *about* 30 seconds long.
So around this: `short[60][61440]` array is my source.

My destination is to put this data into a `byte array`, representing image data. I'm using 16bpp so direct conversion to bytes will be done. This is still not the problematic part.
The problem is i wish to get over with is that i wish to present the data like this: The 60 channels are converted into 12x5 matrixes and 256 samples (1/8 of a second) will be displayed next to each other. Then a next "row" of those and the next... Lemme put up a sketch:
[image: Example]

So if i have a sample of exactly 30 seconds, i get an image of dimensions 3072 x 1200 px. (So 256 samples per 12px on width and 240(30x8) samples per 5 px on heighth)

Can someone provide a clue on how to get this over with?
I've been thinking about a few versions, but none that would really work.

I hope my problem can be understood.

Ok so adding info:

```
bitmap = new Bitmap(60, length, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565);
BitmapData bmpdata = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, 60, length), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565);
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < channel_number; j++)
      { 
         bufferList.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(signalArray[j][i]));
      }
}
```

where the bufferList is defined as `List<byte> bufferList = new List<byte>();`

This is an example where i make an image 60 x 61440 px (channels x time)

What i will do with this image is not the main point. The point is i wish to prepare data to get the desired image as described...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, you want 16bpp, which is 2 bytes, but how does the short value directly convert to rgb?

Comment: I did´t understand what exactly you need. Do you want to accomodate that 3072 x 1200 picture into Full-HD or something like this? Be more specific with your needs.

Comment: Added some info, hopefully i make some more sense now.

Comment: You're throwing numbers around all over the place and it's very confusing. Some of them make sense, but I can't figure out the rest. I get this: `60 channels x 30 seconds x 2,048 samples per second = 3,686,400 samples` & `3072 px x 1200 px = 3,686,400 px`. But `(So 256 samples per 12px on width and 240(30x8) samples per 5 px on heighth)` & `60 x 6114 px (channels x time)` confuse me. I get that you're trying to make a mosaic image from the sample data, but it's not clear how to convert your samples into the mosaic.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo with the example. It's 30 x 61440.

Comment: You will probably want to look at Array.Copy and perhaps the Marshal Class. If you can avoid using a 2-D array it might be best for performance. You can write a function that can access a 1-D array as if it were a 2-D array for access to pixels. And you can write another to access it as an array of arrays so that you can copy rows at a time.

Comment: JerryM i am aware of those functions, i also use them regularly, however the problem here is: how to convert this 2D array in to a 1D array to provide the data for the Bitmap as i wish it to be.